# Error showing when I entered command "apt update"

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (43.255.166.254), connection timed out
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done                              
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (43.255.166.254), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:3:1::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: IPv6 is not working on your network.  Run `sudo apt -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update ` and see if that works.  This forces IPv4 once.  If this works, then we can change your options to use IPv4 by default.  However, we also have a "Connection timed out" on the IPv4 address.  Which suggests the server is offline.

Comment: FYI I emailed the Mirrors team about this as well